# passing data between wordpress pages

Tags: wordpress

I have two simple page. I need to send value of a text box, filled by the user, to another simple page. I have fallowed [How to pass data between wordpress pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9127054/how-to-pass-data-between-wordpress-pages/50227476#50227476instruction). I got the follwoing error:

Warning: sizeof(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in D:\xamp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\allow-php-in-posts-and-pages\allowphp.php on line 175

Warning: sizeof(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in D:\xamp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\allow-php-in-posts-and-pages\allowphp.php on line 364

Here are my code:
the page from which I wanto to send the value:

```
<form >
    <input type ='text' name='discount'/>
    <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/sericves/" title="Yeah yeah!">Link     name</a>;
</form>
```

the second page where i want to receive the value:

```
<h2>Payment of $ [php function=1]</h2>
```

here is the plugin as said by the instruction:

```
<?php
/*
  Plugin name: redirect on post
  Desciption: 

  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13686245/how-to-create-a-custom-url-   based-on-dropdown-in-wordpress-form-submission
I-changed-dropdown-to-field-input
  */ 
  function redirect_on_submit() {
    // check if the post is set
    if (isset($_POST['discount']) && ! empty ($_POST['discount'])) 

 {
    header( "Location: http://localhost/wordpress/sericves/page_id=55& discount=" . $_POST['discount'] );
  }
}
add_action('init', 'redirect_on_submit');
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a session variable just like this.

```
$_SESSION["mykey"]="MyValue";
```

And access this session variable on your other pages.

PS. Make sure to add session_start(); on the top of every page wherever this session variable is being used.

Comment: thanks. I am a newbie in coding and WP. where should I put that? like following:
<form >
<input type ='text' name='discount'/>
<a href="http://localhost/wordpress/sericves/" title="Yeah yeah!">Link name</a>;
</form>
$_SESSION["mykey"]='discount';

I suppse not, since it types out on the screen!

Comment: You can set that session variable on a different page which is called from the form action attribute.
For example
<form action="secondpage.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="myvariable">
<input type="submit">
</form>
And on second page , you can get the textbox value using $_SESSION["mykey"]=$_POST["myvariable"].

Comment: So, in the second page how I assgin the  "myvariable"--which is the name of the textbox in the first page-- to the textbox in the second page?
as follows, won't work:
<?php
session_start()
$_SESSION["discount"]=$_POST["myvariable"]
?>

<form >
<input type ='text' name='discount' value="myvariable"/>
</form>

Comment: You can get that value using PHP.
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['mysessionvar'];?>"
This will set the value of textbox to whatever value you have in your session.
PS mark this as answer if it helped. :)

Comment: I appreciate your help. so, this is what i have done:
first page: <form action="http://localhost/wordpress/sericves/" method="POST">

 <input type="text" name="myvariable" > 
<?php
$_SESSION["mykey"]=$_POST["myvariable"];
?>

<input type="submit"> 
</form> 
P.S : I have tried without the <?php part as well.

the second is:
<form >
<input type="text" value="<?php session_start() echo $_SESSION['myvariable'];?>">
</form>

what I get in the textbox is : 
<?php session_start(); echo $_SESSION['mykey'];?>“><br /></form> </div> </article

Comment: no no, i am yet in trouble. I do not get what i try to pass to the second page using session, instead i get this <form > <input type="text" value="<?php session_start() echo $_SESSION['myvariable'];?>"> </form> what I get in the textbox is : <?php session_start(); echo $_SESSION['mykey'];?>“><br /></form> </div> </article

Comment: Are you doing this on your local system?
Make sure your apache server is up and running.