# how can i call a data created by jquery to another page?

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, call

i have a form in which if i click on different select menu item, different message box  appears just bottom of it. if i want to call the message box data to a page , which code should i use?  i am using a wordpress site.

here is the jquery code i am using for the form

```
 $("#state2").click(function(){
            var val = $(this).val();
            if(val=="TASSUB"){
                $("#location").html('<div class="add_info"><p><strong>Venue:</strong> Henry Jones Art Hotel </p><p style=" add_info-indent: 3.5em;"> 5 Hunter St, Hobart TAS 7000 </P><p><strong>Date: </strong>&nbsp; Monday 15 September</p><p><strong>Time: </strong>&nbsp; 3.00 – 5.00pm</p><p style=" add_info-indent: 3.5em;">(2.30pm arrival for registration and refreshments)</p></div>');
            }
            else if(val=="SASUB"){
                $("#location").html('<div class="add_info"><p><strong>Venue:</strong> Hilton Adelaide </p><p style=" add_info-indent: 3.5em;"> 233 Victoria Square, Adelaide SA 5000 </P><p><strong>Date: </strong>&nbsp; Tuesday 16 September</p><p><strong>Time: </strong>&nbsp; 3.00 – 5.00pm</p><p style=" add_info-indent: 3.5em;">(2.30pm arrival for registration and refreshments)</p></div>');
            }
 });
```

Comment: What does "call the message box data to a page" mean?  I do not understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Similar issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9127054/how-to-pass-data-between-wordpress-pages