# Pass form data to another page in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been working on a wordpress site for the last 2 weeks and I am quite new to this. Currently, I have created a form, where the user can post his username, hit the submit button and some related information will be displayed on top of the same page.

I am accessing a table that I created in the wp database, where username is a foreign key and display the related columns, but i don't know how to pass the $username to a new page.

Here is the form::

```
<div id="container" style="text-align:center;">
   <form method="post" name="myForm">
       <legend><h3>Input</h3></legend>
       <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"/><br>
       <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submitbtn"/>
   </form>
</div>
```

Here is the php code:

```
function get_law() {
   $user = ( isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : '' );

   if( isset( $_POST['submitbtn'] ) ) {
      if ( username_exists( $user ) ) {
          global $wpdb;
          $results = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("Select law, description From mytable Where user_login = %s", $user));
          foreach ( $results as $result ) {
              echo '<div style="text-align:center; background-color: #f1f1c1">
                        <h3 style="font-family:Arial; color:#a83252">
                            '.$result->law.'</h3><br>
                            <font face="Arial" size="20">'.$result->description.'</font>
                        </div>';
          }
      }
      else echo '<p><h3 style="text-align:center; color:red">Username does not exist.</h3></p>';
   } 
} 
add_action('init','get_law');
```

I tried using wp_redirect, but I found out that after redirection, post data are lost.

What I can't figure out is :

1. How to redirect the user to a new page and
2. Display the same - related to the user - data,
3. Why is the current code displaying the related data on the top of the page, even above wordpress primary menu?

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: use **$_SESSION**

Comment: So you are implementing your _own_ user system, instead of using WP functionality for this to begin with? Bad idea IMHO - you should work _with_ the system you are using, not against it.

Comment: _“why is the current code displaying the related data on the top of the page, even above wordpress primary menu?”_ - because you chose the `init` hook for this, which is anything but the right choice for stuff like this.

Comment: Thanks, i ll check $_session. Can you tell me another action then, other than {init} that is more applicable in my case, so that the data are displayed, say, the end of the page?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass data between wordpress pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9127054/how-to-pass-data-between-wordpress-pages)

Comment: I have already seen this page and i cant say it does, it seems to easy to be true. Will the data be saved with bloginfo? Also @jit mentioned $_session

Comment: _“Can you tell me another action then, other than {init} that is more applicable in my case, so that the data are displayed, say, the end of the page?”_ - not really. Which hooks are available regarding that, would very much depend on the specifics of your template. There might not be any at all. (Again, IMHO you are going about this rather wrong from the start already.)

Comment: Used cookies instead, but thanks for your answers!