# Retrieve Data from POST Method and Display in HTML H1 Tag

Tags: javascript, php, html, post, get

**Greetings,**

I am developing a website using WordPress and elementor.
I have a form with the POST method on page1 which is redirecting the user to page2.
How do I receive that data on page2 and display it in the H1 tag on the same page?

Comment: Your question is not quite clear

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass data between wordpress pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9127054/how-to-pass-data-between-wordpress-pages)  You might also search WordPress Stack Exchange for solutions: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I want the display the data I have received from post method on html heading tag

Comment: @Yogi no, because I am able to send data but I just cannot figure out how to receive it on page2 and show in html heading

Comment: The solutions I've seen usually save the form data to session (php $_SESSION[ ]) which can then be reused on other pages. See this related question: [Storing Form Data as a Session Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791414/storing-form-data-as-a-session-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data submitted from a form with the `method='post'` attribute can be accessed using the `$_POST` [superglobal](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php). For example:

```
// page1.php
<form action='/page2.php' method='post'>
    <input type='text' name='name' placeholder='Enter your name' />
    <input type='submit' value='Send' />
</form>
```

```
// page2.php
<?php

$name = $_POST['name'] ?? 'World';

?>

<h1>
    Hello, <?php echo $name; ?>
</h1>
```

Comment: Thank you, but how can I execute this code in elementor page builder in wordpress

Comment: Ideally you could edit the theme files (make a child theme if it's not your own custom theme) - alternatively this looks like it could be a good plugin: [PHP  Code Widget](https://wordpress.org/plugins/php-code-widget/) - I haven't used WordPress for a couple of years now at least so not sure if there are better options