# Follow a link to another site

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, button, slug

I have a WordPress site, let's say there is a post that has a url: https://highthand.com/176-2/, its slug is 176-2, and I need that when I click the download button, I go to the site https://  getsafe.cloud, but so that this slug is displayed in the url, that is, the url looks like this https://getsafe.cloud/176-2.  I can just go to https://getsafe.cloud/176-2, well then I will get an error that the page was not found, and I need the contents of https://getsafe.cloud to be displayed.  How can this be implemented.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by changing the 404 page that came by default in the worpdress Themes. Also you can change url direction of 404 to home directly. Hope yo like the answer.
Thanks

Comment: But each post will have a different slug, the url won't look different every time if I change the 404 page right?

Comment: You can check how to pass slug in the page.. Then you may got what you wanna achieve

Comment: Where can this be done?

Comment: Hey @Ivan213 please check the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9127054/how-to-pass-data-between-wordpress-pages a perfect way to transfer data between the pages..

Comment: And you don't know how to do it?